# Why a Powershell script executes on a previous version of a file that has been changed?

Tags: powershell, file, azure-vm, runcommand

I am trying to modify several values of a PowerShell script template prior to execution. The approach I took was to use the `Get-Content` command to read the template file, then to use the `replace` operand to replace the content with a content of my choosing, and then the `Set-Content` command to update the file, then execute the script. However, according to the error messages that I encounter, it seems that the modified file is not running, but the template one.
The thing I find hard to understand is why, as I use the `Get-Content` once again and print the result prior to execution, where I witness that the file did change.

I use simple PowerShell scripting with no threads or so ever, the script is being executed on an Azure VM via the `Run-Command` feature. I wonder why it happens.
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: I wonder if its caching scripts per-session. Does it still appear to run the old version of the script if you do it via a new powershell session? i.e    Start-Process  pwsh -ArgumentList "pathtoyourscript" -Verb RunAs

Comment: please add your actual code - reduced to the minimum that reproduces the error - to your Question & wrap it in code format markers.

Comment: Instead of templating, you may consider using parameters. This way you don't need to modify the script everytime you run it. [How to use parameters in PowerShell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/)

Comment: I cant I download this script from git and then need to change the endpoint